# How to install mongodb on Redhat Linux PPC64 server

Tags: mongodb, redhat

Hi I am beginner user of linux operating system,

I am trying to install mongodb on my redhat linux server but I could not able to achieve.

I tried in many ways

1. I downloaded a tar file and extracted it after running a mongod I am getting **Cannot execute binary file**
2. I added mongo yum repository

My repo file is :

```
[mongodb-org-3.0]
name=MongoDB org 3.0 Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/5/mongodb-org/3.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

and  I did yum update after that I am running **sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-3.0

I am getting following error

```
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
mongodb-org-3.0                                          |  951 B     00:00
Setting up Install Process
No package mongodb-org-3.0 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

3. I downloaded a rpm file when I am running **rpm -i libmongodb-2.4.9-1.el6.ppc64.rpm**

   **error: Failed dependencies:
                   libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) is needed by libmongodb-2.4.9-1.el6.ppc64
                   libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) is needed by libmongodb-2.4.9-1.el6.ppc64**

I failed in 3 ways . Can you tell me what should I do ?
My system information is

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-358.el6.ppc64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:43:27 EST 2013 ppc64 ppc64 ppc64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: PowerPC is not a supported platform for MongoDB server (as at MongoDB 3.0). The binaries you are trying to install are for `x86_64` architecture (64-bit intel-compatible CPUs) and are not compatible with your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command (as root):

sudo yum install openssl*

Then once packages installed try again to install mongodb-org